# Calling Non-Overidden Method from Child Class object

Tags: java, inheritance

What I am not getting is that the money is picked from the Parent class but this pointer reference belongs to the Child Object?
Both things should have belonged to one scope?

```
class Parent
{
    int money=10;
    Parent parentMethod(){
        System.out.println(money);
        return this;
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    int money=11;

}
public class Demo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child ch=new Child();
        System.out.println(ch.parentMethod());
        System.out.println(ch.parentMethod() instanceof Child);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
demos.Child@1540e19d
10
true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance variables cannot be overridden. `parentMethod()` is defined in `Parent` class, so it only sees the `money` instance variables of `Parent` class.

If you had overridden `parentMethod()` in `Child` class, and accessed the `money` variable in the body of the `Child` class method, you would have seen the value of the `Child` class `money` instance variable.

Comment: Okay, but what is happending with the this variable? Then, according to you I should be getting the reference of Parent this. Because this is also a variable.

Comment: @KamalDua `this` is not an instance variable (in fact it's not any kind of variable - if it was a variable, you could assign to it). `this` is a reference to the current object. The current object in your example is of type `Child`.